# 418: I'm a teapot

Tags: code-golf, internet

As we all should know, [there's a HTTP status code **418: I'm a teapot**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#418).

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to use your creativitea and write the smallest possible server that responds with the above status code to any and every HTTP request made to it.

[Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) apply, including

> #### Fetching the desired output from an external source
>
> This includes doing an HTTP request to fetch the page with the
> question and extracting a solution from that page. This was mildly
> amusing back in 2011, but now is derivative and uninteresting.

Meaning you cannot simply redirect the request to another server to have it return the response.

Your server can do anything (or nothing) while no HTTP request is made to it as long as it replies with the correct response once a HTTP request is made.

Comment: How much use can we make of external libraries? (e.g. using [express](http://expressjs.com/) for a node.js server)

Comment: Should we take the “HTTP” in “any and every HTTP request” literally? I mean, if the request is not HTTP request (or even no request at all, so the client just connects and says nothing), should the server still reply or not?

Comment: Is it strictly HTTP when the server immediately sends a response without waiting for the request? (As most of the answers here are doing.)

Comment: to each and every http request?  Surely just ones to a coffee: URI?

Comment: May we assume we already have root privileges? (e.g. bind() to port 80 is ok)

Comment: @MartinBüttner All libraries are welcome, as many languages have such functionality built-in.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yes, you can assume escalated privileges for your server.

Comment: @manatwork Responding to non-HTTP requests is undefined behavior, meaning your program can do anything (or nothing). As long as it replies with the correct response once a HTTP request is made.

Comment: @billpg See the comment above.

Comment: Most of the answers below do not output the required newlines to signal the end of HTTP response; most browsers would just treat them as prematurely terminated connection.

Comment: @LieRyan Feel free to point out the error to the related answers.

Comment: Would be something like a config line in httpd.conf ok?

Comment: @Knerd I'm leaning on the no side, you're not writing a program, you're simply configuring one.

Comment: omg. With the IOT coming around, this status code may have an actual reason to exist!

Comment: creativitea? iron druid? :D

Comment: @Pietu1998 https://gist.github.com/red-green/474a370f7c3273403827 mine is better

Comment: @Luminous It *was* created for Internet Teapots, and those now exist, so...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 HTeaTeaPot

Comment: @mbomb007 Hyper Tea Transfer Pot.

Comment: Upvoted for creativitea

Answer (score 43):

## GNU Awk: 69 characters

A server itself (endlessly serves one request at a time), no library used.

Send 418 to everybody who connects (<s>82</s> 69 characters):

```awk
BEGIN{while(s="/inet/tcp/80/0/0"){print"HTTP/1.1 418\n"|&s
close(s)}}
```

Send 418 to everybody who sends something (<s>93</s> 80 characters):

```awk
BEGIN{while(s="/inet/tcp/80/0/0"){s|&getline
print"HTTP/1.1 418\n"|&s
close(s)}}
```

Send 418 to everybody who sends a valid HTTP GET request (<s>122</s> 109 characters):

```awk
BEGIN{while(s="/inet/tcp/80/0/0"){s|&getline
if(/^GET \S+ HTTP\/1\.[01]$/)print"HTTP/1.1 418\n"|&s
close(s)}}
```

Comment: But .. how to connect ? ;)

Comment: The same way you connect to any web server. Browser, `netcat`, `telnet`, `wget`, `curl`, another GNU `awk` script, … Theoretically it listens on localhost:80, but for that 1) no web server, Skype or other program should use port 80; 2) you have to be super user to open ports below 1024. So for testing is easier to edit the port number in the script to something like 8080 (`s="/inet/tcp/8080/0/0"`) then connect to that. http://pastebin.com/zauP7LMA

Comment: I see. Cool. Awk noob here :)

Comment: You could possibly save a byte by using smaller port like 8, which is unassigned.

Comment: @HannesKarppila, that's correct. But given that all other solutions which explicitly specify a port (excepting the Haskell answer's port 8888) uses port 80, I better keep it like this for comparability.

Answer (score 33):

### Bash (33)

```
nc -lp80 -q1<<<"HTTP/1.1 418
";$0
```

Comment: Are the two newlines necessary?  Seems to work OK with only one for me.  Also by my count the above is 34 bytes - I'm guessing your editor is adding an unnecessary newline or `\0` to the end of your file - you can `truncate` this and it still works.   `s='echo HTTP/1.1 418|nc -lp80 -q1;$0' ; echo ${#s}` gives 33 for me

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: You are right - the final newline is added automatically in here strings: [Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20157/19702) ------ But I see two possible problems: **1.** The script expects that it is stored in one of the `$PATH` directories or that it is called with a path (recursion by `$0`). ----- **2.** HTTP requires that lines are terminated by `\r\n` not only `\n`. Here string should be `$"HTTP/1.1 418\r\n\r"` (longer readable form). ------ And finally: The script could be shorter: The `-q1` parameter is not necessary.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, @pabouk: The output needs end with two newlines. So one of the newlines was unnecessary (because of the here-string), but the `echo` variant does not work (at least Firefox won't recognize it as a 418). However, the `\r`s aren't needed. The spec says it should be `\r\n\r\n`, but at least Firefox and Chrome will accept `\n\n`, so it seems to be in the spirit of golfing not to include them. The `-q1` parameter was necessary on my system, because the browser will not close the connection by itself. `$0` works fine if the script is made executable and called in that manner.

Comment: @marinus Interesting - I was testing with `wget` which seems to be fine with just one newline

Comment: @pabouk - Interesting snippet here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/OldServers.html: "Lines should be regarded as terminated by the Line Feed, and the preceeding Carriage Return character ignored"

Comment: Regarding `-q1`: I think that the problem you observed could be related to [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) officially defined in HTTP/1.1. I think you should try to use HTTP/1.0 instead. This could work without `-q1`. ------ Regarding `$0` recursion: as the script does not have the shebang sequence and requires root privileges, I called it `sudo bash scriptname`. This does not work if the directory is not in the `$PATH`. ------ I did a mistake in my previous comment. The bash code for CR is `$'\r'` not `$"\r"`.

Comment: @pabouk: making this executable and calling it `sudo ./scriptname.sh` works perfectly fine over here. As for the `-q1`, Firefox doesn't close the connection even with `HTTP/1.0`, so `nc` doesn't end and any further requests will fail.

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, HTTP responses must end in `\r\n`, so you have to use CRLF instead of LF, adding a byte.

Answer (score 32):

### PHP - 85 bytes

```
<?for($s=socket_create_listen(80);socket_write(socket_accept($s),"HTTP/1.1 418
"););
```

Saved with Windows-Style (CR-LF) line endings, requires `php_sockets` enabled.

I actually used this as my error code for the [Hard Code Golf: Create a Chatroom](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12221/) challenge, but no one noticed.

---

**Browser-Friendly version**

```
<?for(socket_getsockname($s=socket_create_listen(80),$n);$t="I'm a teapot";socket_write($c=socket_accept($s),"HTTP/1.0 418 $t
Content-Length: $l

<title>418 $t</title><h1>$t</h1>The requested resource is not suitable for brewing coffee.<hr><i>$n:80</i>"))$l=124+strlen($n);
```

Start the script in the CLI, and point your browser at `http://localhost`.

Comment: +1 for user firendlyness / `I'm a teapot` :-)

Answer (score 22):

## Node.js (LiveScript)

### `http` module - 66

```
require(\http)createServer (->&1.writeHead 418;&1.end!) .listen 80
```

Inspired by [Qwertiy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41663/344).

### `net` module - 76

```
require(\net)createServer (->it.write 'HTTP/1.1 418\r\n';it.end!) .listen 80
```

Answer (score 21):

## Ruby + Rack, 19 bytes

```
run->e{[418,{},[]]}
```

Must be saved as `config.ru`, and run with the `rackup` command.

Or if you prefer "pure" Ruby:

```
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run->e{[418,{},[]]}
```

42 bytes + `-rrack` flag = **48 bytes**

Answer (score 15):

## Bash+BSD general commands, 29

Borrowing back a little bit from other answers:

```
nc -lp80<<<"HTTP/1.1 418
";$0
```

Works for me with `wget`.

#### First answer to use `nc`, 38

```
for((;;)){
nc -l 80 <<<HTTP/1.1\ 418
}
```

I'm assuming root privileges - run as follows:

```
sudo bash ./418.sh
```

Comment: This also assumes that [nc](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) is installed

Comment: @ub3rst4r Correct - That is why I stated "BSD general commands", which may be considered as a "library" from the point of view of shell scripting.  From the OP: "All libraries are welcome"

Comment: A response must end with a newline, see w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Response.html

Comment: @Nit - Yes - bash "here strings" will automatically be appended with a newline

Comment: How about `nc -l 80 <<<HTTP/1.1\ 418;$0`

Comment: The spaces around `80` are not necessary but there is a different problem: HTTP headers section should be terminated by two newlines.

Comment: @pabouk - My version of `nc` seems to expect space between `-l` and `80`; `-lp80` can also be used, though doesn't save anything.  My expectation was the same about the space after 80, but my bash (4.3.11) doesn't like it.  Try `fold -w 1<<<abc` vs `fold -w 1 <<<abc` - the `1<<<abc` is parsed first as a redirection before the rest of the command is expanded.

Comment: @pabouk As for the two newlines, I think this is necessary when content follows, but I think any sensible user agent should be able to handle error header followed by end of connection with just one newline.  At least `wget`, `curl` and chrome Postman REST client seem to be OK.  I couldn't really tell what firefox was doing.

Comment: @pabouk Ok, in the interests of compliance, I've put in 2 newlines.  I was able to save back one byte by using `-lp80<<<` which seems to help the previous bash redirect problem

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the two spaces. I did not notice that you did not use the `-p` switch :) I tested the code with Firefox and without two newlines the status code is not recognized.

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby (nc system command) - 35

```ruby
loop{`nc -l 80 <<<"HTTP/1.1 418"`}
```

DigitalTrauma should get the credit for the idea of using `nc`, however Ruby can make an infinite loop with fewer characters than Bash :)

## Ruby (TCPServer) - 75

```ruby
require'socket'
s=TCPServer.new 80
loop{(s.accept<<'HTTP/1.1 418
').close}
```

That newline is intentional -- the actual newline character is one character shorter than "\n".

## Ruby (WEBrick HTTPServer) - 87

```ruby
require'webrick'
(s=WEBrick::HTTPServer.new).mount_proc(?/){|_,r|r.status=418}
s.start
```

Comment: A response must end with a newline, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Response.html

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, I was going to use that, but then realized the backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash, so it would have been the same number of characters anyway :)

Comment: @TreyThomas Oh I see - so Ruby needs an extra level of escape here

Answer (score 10):

### Node.js, 72

```
require('http').createServer((q,s)=>s.writeHead(418)+s.end()).listen(80)
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a Teapot
Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 16:12:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0
```

---

### Node.js, 80 with ES5 syntax only

```
require('http').createServer(function(q,s){s.writeHead(418);s.end()}).listen(80)
```

The response is

```
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot
Date: Wed, 19 Nov 2014 21:08:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0
```

Comment: I find it just awesome that node supports that error code natively ^^

Comment: You can use arrow functions to lower your byte count.

Comment: @ophact, yep, updated.

Comment: @Qwertiy wow didn't expect a response so quickly on a 6-year old answer

Comment: `ServerResponse#writeHead()` returns itself, so it can be chained with `ServerResponse#end()`: `s.writeHead(418).end()`. -2 to both codes!

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3 106

```
s=__import__('socket').socket(2,1) 
s.bind(('',80))
s.listen(9)
while 1:s.accept()[0].send('HTTP/1.1 418\n')
```

Comment: Based on [hallvabo](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80/hallvabo)'s [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python#comment140_71) in [Tips for golfing in Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python), `from socket import*;s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)` is shorter.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks, is there a shorter way to infinite loop? I didn't find one in the tips...

Comment: `while 1:s.accept()[0].sendall(bytes('HTTP/1.1 418\n','UTF8'))` – unless I missed something. (By the way, feel free to count newlines a single characters, as the language allows them. That way you loose nothing by separating the commands by newlines instead of `;`.)

Comment: You can cut off 2 characters by assuming port 80 is accessible, according to the [question owner's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/418-im-a-teapot/41655#comment96914_41638). One ugly thing which may break portability, but may be acceptable here: use the constants' values directly `s=socket(2,1)` (at least those are their values on my Linux).

Comment: The documentation says for `listen()`'s parameter that “the maximum value is system-dependent (usually 5)”. So instead of 10, 9 is more that enough and 1 character shorter. And instead of `bytes('HTTP/1.1 418\n','UTF8')` a literal `b'HTTP/1.1 418\n'` is enough. Or if you make the code Python 2, then the `b` bytesprefix is not needed anymore. And the shorter `send()` also seems to be enough.

Comment: **106:** `s=__import__('socket').socket(2,1);s.bind(('',80));s.listen(9)
while 1:s.accept()[0].send('HTTP/1.1 418\n')`

Comment: `import socket;s=socket.socket(2,1)` and `s=__import__('socket').socket(2,1)` both have 34 bytes

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell - 142 bytes

```
import Network
import System.IO
main=listenOn(PortNumber 8888)>>=f
f s=do{(h,_,_)<-accept s;hPutStr h"HTTP/1.1 418\r\n";hFlush h;hClose h;f s}
```

Answer (score 7):

## R, 80 characters

Never did socket programming with R before, but I'll give it a try:

```
repeat{s=socketConnection(,80,T,open="r+");cat("HTTP/1.1 418\n",file=s);close(s)}
```

Here `socketConnection` opens a socket: first argument should be the host, the default being `localhost` we can skip it here; the second argument is the port which has no default, then argument `server` when specified `TRUE` creates the socket, if `FALSE` it just connects to an existing one. `T` is, by default, equals to `TRUE`, in R.

**Edit:** As suggested in a suggested edit by @AlexBrown, this could be shorten into **69 characters**:

```
repeat cat("HTTP/1.1 418\n",file=s<-socketConnection(,80,T))+close(s)
```

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, HTTP responses must end in `\r\n`, so you have to add two bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Tcl (>= 8.5), 78 bytes

Edit - added in an extra newline (total of 2 newlines) for the sake of compliance.

```
socket -server {apply {{c - -} {puts $c "HTTP/1.1 418
";close $c}}} 80
vwait f
```

Comment: A response must end with a newline, see w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Response.html

Comment: @Nit - Yes, Tcl puts will automatically append a newline, unless the -nonewline option is given. https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm

Answer (score 6):

## Powershell, 398

```
$Listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("10.10.10.10"), 80)
$Listener.Start()
while($true)
{
    $RemoteClient = $Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
    $Stream = $RemoteClient.GetStream()
    $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $Stream
    $Writer.Write("HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a Teapot`nConnection: Close`n`n")
    $Writer.Flush()
    $RemoteClient.Close()
}
```

## 258

```
$l=New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("10.10.10.10"),80);$l.Start();while($true){$r = $l.AcceptTcpClient();$s = $r.GetStream();$w = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $s;$w.Write("HTTP/1.1 418`n`n");$w.Flush();$r.Close()}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Shell + socat, 60

```
socat tcp-l:80,fork exec:'printf HTTP/1.1\\ 418\\ T\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: ``echo -e HTTP/1.1 418 T\r\n\r`` is shorter.

Comment: The `\\ T` isn't even needed.

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>86</s> 73 bytes

```julia
s=listen(80)
while 1<2
c=accept(s)
write(c,"HTTP/1.1 418

")
close(c)
end
```

Comment: I don't think you need the actual "I'm a teapot" part -- the response code should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it. But as that won't help much on Julia's score I kept it complete. But probably would be better to remove it to facilitate comparison of languages.

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, HTTP responses must end in `\r\n`, so this is invalid. You can fix it at no cost, however, by replacing the first LF with a CR.

Answer (score 5):

## Node.js [**koa**](https://github.com/koajs/koa), 61 Bytes

```
require('koa')().use(function*(){this.status=418}).listen(80)
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot
X-Powered-By: koa
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 07:20:36 GMT
Connection: close

I'm a teapot
```

Requires node v0.11.12 +

Run as:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

Comment: What's `function*`?

Comment: That's a [generator function](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators), part of the ECMAScript 6, Harmony proposal.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, <s>97</s> 86 bytes

Not really a serious contender in terms of absolute byte-count, but I'd like to post it because I didn't think it would be possible to write a fully functional webserver using a mathematical tool. Note the use of [property shortening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48268/32352): `'Ne','s'` internally expands to `'NetworkRole', 'server'`.

```
t=tcpip('0.0.0.0','Ne','s');while 1
fopen(t)
fprintf(t,'HTTP/1.1 418\n')
fclose(t)
end
```

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, HTTP responses must end in `\r\n`, so you have to add two bytes.

Comment: @Makonede Instead of commenting on every single answer here you could've left a single comment on the OP if the `\r\n` is required. Either way, I strongly feel this is not worth digging up a seven year old challenge for...

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 78

```
use Web::Simple;sub dispatch_request{sub{[418,[],[]]}}__PACKAGE__->to_psgi_app
```

run as `plackup whatever.pl`.

Comment: If you want a plack application, then just `sub{[418,[],[]]}` should be sufficient. (16 characters.)

Comment: Of course you're right! It's not like I'm *using* any of the framework, why load it? :)

Comment: @tobyink feel free to submit it as your own though :)

Answer (score 4):

## Go, 162 bytes

```
package main
import "net/http"
func main(){http.HandleFunc("/",func(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){w.WriteHeader(418)})
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7/Django, 94 bytes

(added from default boilerplate from `django-admin.py startproject`)
In urls.py:

```
import django.http.HttpResponse as r;urlpatterns=patterns(url(r'^*$',lambda q:r(status=418)))
```

Answer (score 3):

### node.js with CoffeeScript (76)

```
require("connect")().use((q,s,n)->s.writeHead 418;s.end();return;).listen 80
```

Just compile it to JavaScript, then you need to run `npm install connect`. After that start it with `node server.js`

Answer (score 3):

## Factor, <s>101</s> 141 bytes

```
[ utf8 <threaded-server> readln 10 base> >>insecure [ "HTTP/1.1 418\r" print flush ] >>handler [ start-server ] in-thread start-server drop ]
```

Return 418 to everyone who connects.

Answer (score 2):

## C# + OWIN <s>251</s> 240

I was really hoping it'd be shorter, but the long namespaces ruined that plan. Requires the `Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost` package available on NuGet.

```
using Owin;class P{static void Main(){Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<P>("http://localhost");while(0<1);}public void Configuration(IAppBuilder a){a.Run(c=>{c.Response.StatusCode=418;return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);});}}
```

Answer (score 2):

### node.js with connect (78)

```
require('connect')().use(function(q,s,n){s.writeHead(418);s.end()}).listen(80)
```

You need to run `npm install connect` first. Then start it with `node server.js`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with minimal effort using a `.htaccess` file and php.

All the accesses to your server will return the status 418.

Below is the code:

## .htaccess (28 bytes)

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

## PHP (<s>38</s> 19 bytes)

```
<<?header(TE,1,418);
```

---

Thanks to [@primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo) for saving me a bunch of bytes!

---

I have tested this and confirm it returns the desired result!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLb9p.png]

By the way, "Pedido" means "Request" and "Resposta" means "Answer".

Comment: -1, this is not a complete program. It relies on an external web server.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Actually, it relies on Apache with PHP installed as a module. Your argument is both valid and invalid. Apache only redirects the accesses to the PHP file, the PHP file takes care of the code.

Comment: @nyuszika7h If we go down on that layer, then you can't even use the console to run your PHP code. Apache is the starter. The trigger that fires the bullet. Running the PHP file from the console, would make the console the trigger.

Comment: You're relying on having Apache already running, and I don't think it will work without changing the default configuration either. I don't care what you say, there's no way I can see this as being valid. But you should ask @Nit, as it's their question.

Comment: @nyuszika7h If it was invalid, the OP would have said already.

Comment: `.htaccess` is not even code, it's just a limited configuration file. If this is valid (which apparently it is, judging by the fact that the OP hasn't said anything) then I'll eat my hat. Seriously though.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Which seasoning you will wish sir? And according to your comment, then my char count should be reduced to 38 bytes, since that is the only *programming* part with *real* code.

Comment: That alone isn't valid, someone else already tried that.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Any evidence to support your statement?

Comment: [Revision history of said post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/41639/revisions#spacer-584efecc-4af4-4501-b805-6b2e06f43746). But if that isn't enough, I'm sure @Nit will be glad to confirm that the original version of that was invalid.

Comment: @nyuszika7h That's just an edit log. Nothing *important* to see there.

Comment: The comments were deleted because they're obsolete. That's just how Stack Exchange works. Like I said, I'm sure the OP (or the person who wrote that answer) will be glad to confirm.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Let me tell you a story. A few days ago, I answered a question on stackoverflow (the rules are almost the same, you will see). And one user decided to "bash" me and the OP, both for our low reputation and me for answering it and the OP for asking it. And then, all the comments where deleted. I posted on meta (I can provide a link)  asking what I could do in case of such a situation. Their answer was that without comments, there is nothing that can be done. Here is the same case: if you want me to delete this answer, prove me it is invalid. Deleted comments aren't enough evidence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19217/discussion-between-nyuszika7h-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: Old question, but I just noticed that `<?header(TE,1,418);` will also return status 418 (6 bytes shorter than `<?header("HTTP/1.1 418");`).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 208 bytes

```
import java.net.*;class R{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(80);;){Socket p=s.accept();p.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.0 418\n".getBytes());p.close();}}}
```

This question needed a java answer.

```
poke@server ~
$ curl -i localhost:80
HTTP/1.0 418
```

Comment: Where is status message?

Comment: @Qwertiy I think this question only asks for status code which I interpret as the integer, so it follows that the status message/reason is not strictly required.

Comment: Not me to deside, but I think it should be with status text.

Comment: Get Java 8 already >_>

Comment: [Here it is as a lambda for 148 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDBTsMwDL3vK6ydEqSFTeIwKSoHJCQuCKROXIBDyLySLk2qxG1BUb@9pOtl4vRsv2c/27Xq1aY@nifTtD4Q1DkXDkncSG1VjPCsjEvGEYaT0gglhh5D6r05QiQViL3NYc/pO/ghwuOPxpaMd3Jsuy9r9KyiDJeOJg9jJQXjqvdPUKGKHP43psUC4gIFTP3mPp18YAtRen1Gglg4HOC6xPZbLiVPlxOMFy8dtR1lN1QNUBGF0rMF46JCuiYZlySGYAjZ@ulweL3diS3c7fYfbj1LH34JI@OzSFsfMcvHcZKrZUGxfMF11nK5ysQf)

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, HTTP responses must end in `\r\n`, so you have to add two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) + [`ncat`](https://nmap.org/ncat), <s>75</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> <s>62</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

*-12 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*.

```
'‚«™’ÿ.¬•"n—Ä -k¯à80<<<'HTTP/1.1 418
'"’.E
```

Your ISP must be AT&T for this to work, as it abuses AT&T's automatic conversion of `\n` to `\r\n` in HTTP requests.

```erl
'‚«™’...’.E  # trimmed program
         .E  # evaluate...
    ’...’    # "ÿ.shell\"ncat -klp80<<<'HTTP/1.1 418\n'\""...
             # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
'‚«          # "system"...
   ™         # in title case...
         .E  # as Elixir code

====================

System.shell"..."  # trimmed program
System.shell       # execute shell command...
            "..."  # literal

====================

ncat -klp80<<<'...'  # trimmed program
ncat                 # host web server...
     - l             # that listens to requests...
     -k              # forever...
     -  p            # on port...
         80          # literal...
ncat                 # that returns response input...
           <<<       # with...
              '...'  # literal...
           <<<       # as input
```

<sub>Side note: I do not know Elixir at all so if there are ways to improve the Elixir code please let me know.</sub>

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) + [`ncat`](https://nmap.org/ncat), <s>64</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
’__£Ø__('ï´').‚«("n—Ä -k¯à80<<<'HTTP/1.1 418\n'")’.E
```

---

```py
’...’.E  # trimmed program
     .E  # evaluate...
’...’    # "__import__('os').system(\"ncat -klp80<<<'HTTP/1.1 418\n'\")"...
     .E  # as Python code

====================

__import__('os').system("...")  # trimmed program
__import__('os').system(     )  # execute shell command...
                        "..."   # literal

====================

ncat -klp80<<<'...'  # trimmed program
ncat                 # host web server...
     - l             # that listens to requests...
     -k              # forever...
     -  p            # on port...
         80          # literal...
ncat                 # that returns response input...
           <<<       # with...
              '...'  # literal...
           <<<       # as input
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know 05AB1E also supported running as Elixir code, TIL.

Comment: @Etheryte Yeah, 05AB1E is actually written in Elixir, that's why this was added.

Comment: In the new version `.E` can evaluate single Elixir expressions, you don't need to write a full program. Did you test the current version? For me I couldn't get it to work, but [this](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc4MriktRcveKM1JwcpbxkBd2cAgsDGxsbdY@QkAB9Qz1DBRNDC3UloEo91///AQ) should work with the newest Elixir version.

Comment: @ovs Thanks for the tip about `System.shell`! About the comment: I am aware of that, however the `nc` needs to run infinitely, thus I made a recursive function. (Doesn't seem to be a better way of making an infinite loop in Elixir)

Comment: I found a way to do it without defining a module: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcNFu16ODK4pLUXL3ijNScHA2lvGQF3ZwCCwMbGxt1j5CQAH1DPUMFE0MLdSVNHTVDPQ01Q81Y6zQ9jTRNoHY91///AQ "05AB1E – Try It Online") (Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949785/6346504))

Answer (score 1):

## nginx - 35

```
events{}http{server{return 418;}}
```

Throw that in nginx.conf, start nginx.

*Not sure if this uses standard loopholes "Using built-in functions to do the work" or "Interpreting the challenge too literally." [Oops, looks like OP won't like this answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/418-im-a-teapot#comment97015_41638)*

Comment: Would it still work if you dropped the `;`?

Comment: +4/-4: well done on controversy :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + Flask, <strike>64</strike> <strike>80</strike> <strike>76</strike> 75 bytes

```python
from flask import*
a=Flask("");a.route("/")(lambda:abort(418));a.run("",80)
```

I don't know much Flask, so I'm not entirely sure if this works. Please let me know in the comments if there's some problem with this. Ungolfed version:

```python
from flask import Flask, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    abort(418)

app.run("127.0.0.1", 80)
```

Simply binds the path "/" to a function that aborts with error code 418.

*Thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede) for pointing out that I didn't start the server and giving a modification to make the solution <strike>80</strike> <strike>76</strike> 75 bytes. The 80 was from using `app` instead of `a`. Oops! The 76 was from `(a:=Flask(""))` instead of `a=Flask("");a`.*

Comment: You never started the server. Working 80 byte solution: `from flask import*;(app:=Flask('')).route('/')(lambda:abort(418));app.run('',80)`

Comment: wait i'm dumb why use `app` when you can use `a` lol. Saves 4 bytes

Comment: @Makonede Oops! I didn't catch that either, hehe.

Comment: Also -1 without `:=`: `a=Flask('');a.route('/')(lambda:abort(418));a.run('',80)`

Comment: @Makonede Oops. Right again, Makonede!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org) + [`ncat`](https://nmap.org/ncat), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```py
import os;os.system("ncat -klp80<<<'HTTP/1.1 418\n'")
```

Your ISP must be AT&T for this to work.

```py
import os;os.system("...")  # trimmed program
import                      # import module named...
       os                   # variable
          os.system(     )  # run shell command...
                    "..."   # literal

====================

ncat -klp80<<<'...'  # trimmed program
ncat                 # host web server...
     - l             # that listens to requests...
     -k              # forever...
     -  p            # on port...
         80          # literal...
ncat                 # that returns response input...
           <<<       # with...
              '...'  # literal...
           <<<       # as input
```