# Leave a Comment

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

**Task:**

Make a program that leaves a comment on this question. The content should be `1234567890123456`.

**Edits:**

1. You may leave your usernames and passwords as `U` and `P` if you are
   using username and password. (if applicable)
2. No URL Shorteners (if applicable)
3. You may not use the browser console.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Interesting first post! Seems a bit hard in most languages though, but I think it's good anyway.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your inbox at the end of this challenge...

Comment: You should maybe make a post on Meta where people can test their submissions, but this is completely optional.

Comment: @Loovjo You can always delete your comment

Comment: @Bálint That may be a bit tedious to do every time you test the program.

Comment: @Loovjo I can only post once every 40 minutes :( but I made the page.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you decide to post on meta, you should maybe use another account, since you'll be getting a lot of unnecessary notifications otherwise.

Comment: I don't think creating a meta post to test answers is a good idea.

Comment: To the people testing their code: please delete your comment(s) after you submit them, to keep the comments on this challenge from getting unnecessarily long and spammy, and to make the mods' jobs easier.

Comment: Also, retrieving the `access_token` from a browser session is difficult (if not impossible) for some languages.

Comment: Does nobody else think this is underspecified? Like, how the hell do I do that? Aren't questions meant to be self-contained? Where's the link to the API docs?

Comment: @cat While I agree that the specifications are rather sparse, I think it's because there just isn't a whole that needs to be said. Also note that using the Stack Exchange API isn't required by the question, so including API docs in the question would be rather superfluous.

Comment: This works on specific languages only. Many languages do not support Internet.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because looking at the existing answers and comments it seems to me that this needs a) to explicitly white-list the permitted inputs (on a plain reading answers may take no input, but some of them seem to be taking auth details and bypassing the implied requirement to use username and password to log in); b) to clarify what is meant by "*You may leave your usernames and passwords as U and P, respectively*" (which I would interpret as telling us to hardcode "U" and "P", but which others have clearly interpreted differently).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the suggestions. I edited the question just now. Are there any other suggestions you would like me to add?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by URL shorteners? Clearly bit.ly and goo.gl would not be disallowed, but what about http://ppcg.lol, which is a custom domain owned by Quill that redirects to this site?

Comment: @Mego if you want to access this question, you have to use codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546 and not ppcg.lol/q/84546 (I commented to Sirens to change his answer because he used ppcg)

Comment: 1234567890123456 (this is not sent by script :P)

Comment: 12345678901‌​23456

Comment: 12345678901‌​23456

Comment: 123456789023456

Comment: 123456789023456

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Javascript with jQuery, 127 bytes

```js
$.post("//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/84546/comments",{comment:"12345678901‌​23456",fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey})
```

Thanks to Ismael Miguel and nicael for a few bytes.

The `fkey` parameter is unique to your account, and can be found by examining local storage contents of your browser with a StackExchange page open. This code must be run in a browser with an open StackExchange session present. It automatically loads the `fkey` parameter from the browser's local storage (previous versions of this submission required it to be manually entered).

Unfortunately, the `ppcg.lol` URL can't be used, because it doesn't pass POST requests through.

Fun fact: if you attempt to run this code without the proper `fkey` value, you get an [HTTP 418](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41638/45941) response:

[image: teapot]

Example of how to find the `fkey` value in Chrome:

[image: fkey]

Apparently Winterbash stuff is still being stored. Neat.

For reference, the same thing in vanilla Javascript would be 314 bytes (thanks again to Ismael Miguel and nicael for some bytes off):

```js
with(new XMLHttpRequest()){
open("POST","//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/84546/comments",1)
setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
setRequestHeader("Content-length",62)
setRequestHeader("Connection","close")
send("comment=1234567890123456&fkey="+StackExchange.options.user.fkey}))}
```

Comment: I was just about to write this. Please add a Stack Snippet.

Comment: I like how you use the request to access the site instead of using selenium!

Comment: @NoOneIsHere A Stack Snippet isn't possible, because they run sandboxed, without access to the browser's cookie/session data. Additionally, I'm not certain if Stack Snippets even allow POST requests at all.

Comment: Instead of `var http=new XMLHttpRequest();with(http){`, you can do `with(new XMLHttpRequest()){`. Alternativelly, you can drop the `http:` from your URLs. Also, `{"comment":"1234567890123456","fkey":localstorage.getItem('se:fkey')}` can be just ``{comment:1234567890123456,fkey:localStorage.getItem`se:fkey`}``. Notice that you wrote `localstorage`, when it **MUST** be `localStorage`. Final result: ``$.post("//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/84546/comments",{comment:1234567890123456,fkey:localStorage.getItem`se:fkey`})`` (121 bytes)

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer. Not because my solution was completelly disregarded, but because it just simply doesn't work with `localstorage`. You **MUST** have `localStorage`!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Downvoting for accidentally missing the capitalization on one letter in code seems a bit ridiculous, but that's your call. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Mego No. Downvoting because it **is** broken is **NOT** ridiculous.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Downvoting because of a slight typo is.

Comment: @Mego Still broken. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Try it now - it was actually some of your golfing suggestions that broke it, along with me missing that the `se:fkey` parameter from `localStorage` needed to be sliced.

Comment: @Mego The `"broken"` part refered to `localstorage` not working. My suggestions weren't perfect, but, I wasn't expecting you to use them anyway. The only one I expected was changing `localstorage` to have the correct spelling. Incorrect spelling of it means that the answer won't work as is broken.

Comment: `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` is shorter than `localStorage["se:fkey"].slice(0,32)` :)

Answer (score 15):

## AppleScript with Safari, <s>269</s> 287 bytes

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
tell window 1
set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84546"})
delay 5
do JavaScript "$('a')[66].click();$('textarea')[0].val('1234567890123456');$('input')[5].click()" in current tab
end tell
end tell
```

To use this you need to enable Safari Developer Settings and then enable `Allow JavaScript from Apple Events`. I'm not sure if it's cheating or not to use the existing keychain + cookies but oh well.

I also managed to do this in OSX's Automator by just automating the clicks and keystrokes however I didn't think it stayed true to the idea of the challenge

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is great! That's not cheating. You also need to enable JS for *all* JavaScript answers.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! While this is certainly a creative answer, it is not self-contained, as it does not take the username and password as input.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Totally understand but the line between self contained and not gets a little blurry with this sort of prompt considering all the moving parts you need. Mego's answer involves pulling the token out of Chrome's traffic analyzer which is where I'd personally draw the grey area line. Mine's most certainly not entirely self contained that's for sure'

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nowhere in the challenge does it say that taking the username and password as input is required. In fact, all it does say is (paraphrased) "post this comment to this question" and "you may leave username and password as U and P, respectively". This submission fulfills the requirements, and thus is valid.

Comment: @Sirens Thanks for the answer. I just edited the question so can you not use URL Shorteners?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work... I mean, it does click the flag link, not the commenting link.

Comment: The OP modified the challenge to disallow URL shorteners, which invalidates this answer until you swap ppcg.lol for codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm temporarily removing this post in compliance with our [policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7990) for the reasons cited above. Please feel free to edit your answer and to flag it for moderator attention so it can be undeleted.

Comment: @nicael What OS version are you on? This still works for me on Sierra beta 6

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3.5 with Selenium Webdriver, <s>485</s> <s>427</s> <s>469</s> <s>461</s> <s>449</s> <s>414</s> 403 bytes:

```python
from selenium.webdriver import*;import time;D=Chrome();I=lambda k:D.find_element_by_name(k);C='comment';D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/login');I('email').send_keys(U);Z=I('password');Z.send_keys(P);Z.submit();D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546');D.find_element_by_link_text('add a '+C).click();E=I(C);E.send_keys('1234567890123456');time.sleep(1);E.submit()
```

A full program utilizing a simple Python selenium web driver solution. Works in Chrome, although it needs [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) installed to work. Works by renaming `U` and `P` to the user's Stack Exchange email and password, respectively. However, if there are any issues getting ChromeDriver installed, here is a FireFox solution that gets executed in the exact same manner as the above solution and does not need any drivers, although it is currently 1 byte longer at **<s>414</s> 404 bytes**:

```python
from selenium.webdriver import*;import time;D=Firefox();I=lambda k:D.find_element_by_name(k);C='comment';D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/login');I('email').send_keys(U);Z=I('password');Z.send_keys(P);Z.submit();D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546');D.find_element_by_link_text('add a '+C).click();E=I(C);E.send_keys('1234567890123456');time.sleep(1);E.submit()
```

Also, if a function is wanted, here is a solution using an anonymous lambda function, currently standing at **<s>513</s> <s>455</s> <s>497</s> <s>489</s> <s>477</s> <s>449</s> 431 bytes** and using Chrome as the browser.

```python
lambda U,P:exec("from selenium.webdriver import*;import time;D=Chrome();I=lambda k:D.find_element_by_name(k);C='comment';D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/login');I('email').send_keys(U);Z=I('password');Z.send_keys(P);Z.submit();D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546');D.find_element_by_link_text('add a '+C).click();E=I(C);E.send_keys('1234567890123456');time.sleep(1);E.submit()",locals())
```

However, if there are, again, any issues regarding ChromeDriver, here is the same type of solution but this time using Firefox, currently standing at **<s>442</s> 432 bytes**:

```python
lambda U,P:exec("from selenium.webdriver import*;import time;D=Firefox();I=lambda k:D.find_element_by_name(k);C='comment';D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/login');I('email').send_keys(U);Z=I('password');Z.send_keys(P);Z.submit();D.get('http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546');D.find_element_by_link_text('add a '+C).click();E=I(C);E.send_keys('1234567890123456');time.sleep(1);E.submit()",locals())
```

You call these lambda functions by simply renaming the function as anything valid and then calling with your email and password like a normal function. For instance, if the function were named `H`, you would call it like `H(Email, Password)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing me to Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: @Maltysen No problem. :)

Comment: `Chrome` is shorter than `Firefox`?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Well, I could not get it working with Webdriver before. I finally have though, and my solution is now 11 bytes shorter! :D

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 2.2 on iOS, 380 bytes

```
let r = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/84546/comments")!)
r.HTTPMethod = "POST"
r.HTTPBody = try!NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["comment":"1234567890123456","fkey":UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("localstorage.getItem('se:fkey')")!],options:[])
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(r).resume()
```

Assumes the user is logged in to Code Golf with Safari and has cookies enabled.  Also assumes UIKit is implicitly imported and available.  JSON serialization is so verbose in Cocoa...  Might update this with a Swift 3 solution and optionally macOS/Linux testable answers.

Comment: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` brilliant

Comment: @cat [it gets better](https://github.com/Quotation/LongestCocoa).

Comment: I'm angry now. I didn't think it was possible to hate Obejctive-C more than I did...

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 with Selenium Webdriver, 684 bytes:

```
import java.util.*;import org.openqa.selenium.*;import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;class Leave_a_Comment_PPCG_Challenge_Golfed_Version_1{static void Y(String U,String P){WebDriver D=new FirefoxDriver();D.get("http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/login");D.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(U);WebElement Z=D.findElement(By.name("password"));Z.sendKeys(P);Z.submit();D.get("http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84546");D.findElement(By.linkText("add a comment")).click();WebElement V=D.findElement(By.name("comment"));V.sendKeys("1234567890123456");D.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add Comment']")).click();}public static void main(String[]a){Scanner I=new Scanner(System.in);Y(I.next(),I.next());}}
```

A direct adaptation in Java 8 of my second full program answer in [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84570/52405). Works perfectly in Firefox and asks for space separated email and password input immediately when the program starts. In other words, the input is in the format `Email Password` where the space in between the two is needed.

Comment: The code you have here is longer than 684, haha