# Smallest web server

Tags: code-golf

**Create your smallest web server in your preferred language!**

Requirements

Must respond to atleast 1 type of request (get,post,patch,delete), with a specified string.
Smallest implementation wins!
*String can be empty

You may use any library you want

My personal record for this was 56B in node

```
require('express')().use((r,w)=>w.send('')).listen(8080)
```

Comment: I could return a 404 if you want

Comment: Sure, anything that works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [418: I'm a teapot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/418-im-a-teapot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) with [MiServer](http://miserver.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```
Start'.'
```

Starts a website on port 8080 serving the current directory.

This is what an interactive session transcript can look like:

```
      )xload miserver
.\miserver.dws saved Thu Apr  4 23:27:46 2019
      Start'.'
Virtual alias "PlugIns" overrides site path of same name.
MiServer for "." started on http://10.101.1.172:8080
Running in Debug mode (configured by setting <Production> in /Config/Server.xml)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with -m http.server, 11 bytes

No code. Just run python.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBP/yC0oy8/OK/@vmKmSUlBToFacWlaUWAQA)

Comment: Isn't that 0 bytes with a language of "Python 3 -m http.server"?

Comment: The inclusion of "http.server" on the command line accounts for the 11 bytes.

Comment: Yeah but isnt that just equivalent to a compiler flag.. like -u in c#